# Checking if a DateTime value is more than N days old

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a procedure that is meant to delete items in my T-SQL database that are more than a specified number of days old. It starts out like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FlushLinks (string numDaysOld)
    {
        // Deletes all database references to links were submitted over numDaysOld days ago

        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (LinkDate thisLinkDate in PD.dates)
        {
            TimeSpan thisTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(numDaysOld), 0, 0, 0);
            if ((currentDateTime - thisLinkDate.dtime) > thisTimeSpan)
            {
                foreach (AssetLink thislink in PD.links) if (thislink.linkguid == thisLinkDate.linkguid) PD.links.DeleteOnSubmit(thislink);
```

but for some reason isn't working because when I called it with `numDaysOld=30` it deleted all everything including items with recent stamps (`2015-06-18 16:36:00`, `2015-06-18 16:10:00`, etc., of type `smalldatetime` in my database)

Is there anything obviously wrong about my procedure?

Comment: ever tried DateTime.Now.AddDays(-N) which will give you the day before N days from now

Comment: Agree with @DanHunex. It would be a lot easier to calculate `var  thresholdDate = currentDateTime.AddDays(-numDays)`  and then just do a simple `if (thisLinkDate.dtime < thresholdDate)`

Comment: Is `-numDays` valid syntax and did I need to do `0-numDays` (I'm new to C#)?

Comment: Also what is `PD`? It look suspiciously like you are trying to keep two separate collections (`dates` and `links`) in sync, which is bound to cause you trouble. If `PD` was instead a collection of objects with a `date` and a `link` property, it would be much easier to remove the object when you find one that is out of date and it wouldn't involve looping over the `links` every for every date in `dates` that is old.

Comment: well -numDays means negative of that number....so you can do -1* numDays for actual implementation...

Comment: Assuming `numDays` is a number, then yes, you don't need to do `0-numDays` to negate it. It the unitary `-` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare the dates by using the DateTime.AddDays() function, since it's the day portion of the date that you're specifically interested in.  Here's a small example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int limitDays = 5;
        DateTime[] dates = 
        {
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), // falls within 5 days.
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) // does not fall within 5 days.
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Limit: " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-limitDays).ToString() + " (" + limitDays.ToString() + " days)");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var date in dates)
        {
            if (DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-limitDays)) < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Outside the limit: " + date.ToString());
            }
            else if (DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-limitDays)) >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Within the limit: " + date.ToString());
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```